# Numpy array addition made as simple as np.einsum()?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

If I have `a.shape = (3,4,5)` and `b.shape = (3,5)`, using `np.einsum()` makes broadcasting then multiplying the two arrays super easy and explicit:

```
result = np.einsum('abc, ac -> abc', a, b)
```

But if I want to ***add*** the two arrays, so far as I can tell, I need two separate steps so that the broadcasting happens properly, and the code feels less explicit.

```
b = np.expand_dims(b, 1)
result = a + b
```

Is there way out there that allows me to do this array addition with the clarity of `np.einsum()`?

Comment: Only `einsum` uses that index notation, and it only works for `sum-of-product`.  It can also be used to change the dimensions of individual arrays.  But in your case, you just need to become comfortable the more direct ways of adding dimensions and `broadcasting`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for the clarification! You mentioned einsum can change the dimensions of individual arrays, would you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadcasting can occur only on one extra [dimension](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). For adding these two arrays one could expand them in a one-liner as follows:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(3,4,5); b = np.random.rand(3,5);
c = a + b[:, None, :] # c is shape of a, broadcasting occurs along 2nd dimension
```

Note this is not any different than `c = a + np.expand_dim(b, 1)`. In terms of clarity it is a personal style thing. I prefer broadcasting, others prefer einsum.